# Android - inconsistent ringtone behavior

Tags: android

I am trying to add ringtones to the media/ringtones folder from my application. If the phone is connected via USB to a computer or mounted on my Mac, the ringtones do not show up in the SD Card, nor in the Ringtone settings.

But if I run the application with the USB unplugged, the ringtones appear ok. This is not a problem with Ringdroid which does the same thing.

Can someone please tell me what could be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check the setting for usb mass storage? It should be off if you want to access the content of the sd card from the phone.

Comment: Thanks Mariano. Ringtones saved using ringdroid work fine. So i guess the access is not a problem. and I see the ringtones saved from my app after i restart the phone.

Answer (score 0):

If you mount the SDCard on your Mac, your Phone can´t acces it.

So, if you want to use the SDCard on your phone, it has to be mounted there (and nowhere else).